# Divergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\text{ d}x$ for $t$ in some neighborhood of $0$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

I wish to show 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\text{ d}x$$ for $t$ in some neighborhood of $0$ is divergent.

Is this a valid proof?

The Taylor series for $e^x$ is 
$$e^x = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3) \geq\dfrac{x^2}{2}$$
since we are given $x \geq 0$. If we suppose $t > 0$, then of course, 
$$te^x \geq \dfrac{x^2}{2}$$
so that the exponent $$te^x - \dfrac{x^2}{2} \geq 0$$
and hence
$$e^{te^x - x^2/2} \geq e^0 = 1$$
since $e^{\cdot}$ is non-decreasing, and hence
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\text{ d}x \geq \int_{0}^{\infty}1\text{ d}x = \infty\text{.}$$

Comment: So far so good. But what about $t<0$?

Comment: From $e^x\ge\dfrac{x^2}2$ you get $te^x\ge\dfrac{x^2}2$, but you have only assumed that $t>0$ not that $t>1$... Please have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assume $t>0$. Since $$ \lim_{x \to
       \infty}\frac{e^x}{\frac{x^2}2}=\infty $$ then there exists $x_0>0$
   such that for all $x>x_0$, $$ \frac{e^x}{\frac{x^2}2}>\frac1t,\qquad
   te^x-\frac{x^2}2>0, $$ giving, for any $M>x_0$, $$ \begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{M}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\:dx&=\int_{0}^{x_0}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\:dx+\int_{x_0}^{M}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\:dx
   \\\\&>\int_{0}^{x_0}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\:dx+\int_{x_0}^{M}1\:dx
   \\\\&>M-x_0 \end{align} $$ yielding, as $M \to \infty$, the
   *divergence* of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\:dx$ in this case.
2. Assume $t\le0$. Then $$ te^x-\frac{x^2}2\le -\frac{x^2}2, $$ giving
   $$ 
   \begin{align}
       \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(te^x-x^2/2)\:dx&\le\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2/2)\:dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}},\end{align}
   $$ the given integral is  *convergent* in this case.